# Insert single numerical value into MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql

The query I'm trying to run is:

```
INSERT INTO albumtest (on) VALUES ('3')
```

Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.21

Syntax Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'on) VALUES ('3')' at line 1

I've been looking over this for almost a day now, and I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this syntax error.

Full code is here: http://pastebin.com/6mMbZ1Y1

But I know the rest of it is fine, because it can run other queries fine `(such as $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (title) VALUES ('".$title."')";)`

Comment: you need to wrap the ``on`` into tick... maybe because it is a reserve word..

Comment: Yes, `ON` is in the [MySQL list of Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the correct syntax

```
INSERT INTO `albumtest` (`on`) VALUES ('3')
```

Comment: Wow, It was originally order but I shortened it because I assumed 'order' would of been a keyword. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: you're welcome :) .. use the backticks always, even if the word is not reserved, and peace your mind

Comment: Still getting the syntax error >.< Error: INSERT INTO albumtest ('on') VALUES ('3')

Comment: use `on` not 'on' .. use backtick not apostrophe

Answer (score 1):

ON is `reserved keyword` of mysql it should be write inside `backtics`

```
INSERT INTO albumtest (`on`) VALUES ('3')
```

Answer (score 0):

`on` is MySql reserved keyword. Dont use it as column name.

Comment: do not answer if already same answer is present

Comment: they are both answered at the same time